# Binned scatterplot -- how to ensure the top 'viewable' is the item in the bin with the lowest value in a column?

Tags: pandas, visualization, altair

I have a binned scatterplot:

```
scatterplot = alt.Chart(locations).mark_circle(
    size=300
).encode(
    alt.X('reprLong:Q', bin=True),
    alt.Y('reprLat:Q', bin=True),
    color=alt.Color('featureType:N', legend=None),
    tooltip=['minDate:Q', 'title:N', 'featureType:N']
).interactive().add_selection(selector)
```

For each item in the bin, this seemingly layers on circles for every item, with no apparent order. I'd like the top item (the 'visible' one you can click) to be the item in the bin with the lowest `minDate` (column in pandas dataframe `locations`) value. How do I do that? I have it interactive, so I need only those items to be viewable / clickable.

Comment: Could you please create a reproducible example with a publically available dataset? You could use the sample vega datasets used in the Altair documentation. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Do you actually want multiple values stacked on top of each other with the minValue on top, or do you just want to show the single minValue?